# raise KeyError(key) in pandas while using apply function and trying get 2 input

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want in .apply function get 2 entities and check it but I got `pandas.errors.IndexingError: Too many indexers` error.

```
import pandas as pd

dict2 = {
    "name": ["kambiz", "ali", "mmd", "sara"],
    "age": [19, 19, 14, 12],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict2)


def show_if(age, name):
    if age == 19:
        if name == "kambiz":
           return "you are kambiz and 19"
        elif name == "ali":
           return "you are ali and 19"
    else:
        return "not available"


df["19 ages"] = df.apply(lambda x: show_if(x.loc[:, x["age"]], x.loc[:, x["name"]]), axis=1)
print(df)
```

How got two entities and more then check it ? Thanks for your help .

Comment: I have a same problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `apply` but rather a vectorial approach:

```
import numpy as np

df["19 ages"] = np.where(df['age'].eq(19),
                         '19 in this group is '+df['name'],
                         'not available')
```

Output:

```
     name  age                     19 ages
0  kambiz   19  19 in this group is kambiz
1     ali   17               not available
2     mmd   14               not available
3    sara   12               not available
```

Comment: please review my quesetion